# Using antlr to parse a | separated file

Tags: antlr

So I think this should be easy, but I'm having a tough time with it.  I'm trying to parse a | delimited file, and any line that doesn't start with a | is a comment.  I guess I don't understand how comments work.  It always errors out on a comment line.  This is a legacy file, so there's no changing it.  Here's my grammar.

```
grammar Route;

@header {
package org.benheath.codegeneration;
}

@lexer::header {
package org.benheath.codegeneration;
}

file: line+;
line: route+ '\n';
route: ('|' elt) {System.out.println("element: [" + $elt.text + "]");} ;
elt: (ELEMENT)*;

COMMENT: ~'|' .* '\n' ;
ELEMENT: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'*'|'_'|'@'|'#') ;
WS: (' '|'\t') {$channel=HIDDEN;} ; // ignore whitespace
```

Data:

```
! a comment
Another comment
| a | abc | b | def | ...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Small tip: You should indent code by 4 spaces which will cause this site to parse and show it as code, which can be done by highlighting the block and pressing the "Code" button at the top or hitting Ctrl+K.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first post to Stack Overflow, and thanks for the warm welcome.

Answer (score 1):

A grammar for that would look like this:

```
parse
  :  line* EOF   
  ;

line
  :  ( comment | values ) ( NL | EOF )
  ;

comment
  :  ELEMENT+
  ;

values
  :  PIPE ( ELEMENT PIPE )+
  ;

PIPE
  :  '|'    
  ;

ELEMENT
  :  ('a'..'z')+
  ;

NL
  :  '\r'? '\n' |  '\r' 
  ;

WS
  :  (' '|'\t') {$channel=HIDDEN;} 
  ;
```

And to test it, you just need to sprinkle a bit of code in your grammar like this:

```
grammar Route;

@members {
  List<List<String>> values = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
}

parse
  :  line* EOF   
  ;

line
  :  ( comment | v=values {values.add($v.line);} ) ( NL | EOF )
  ;

comment
  :  ELEMENT+
  ;

values returns [List<String> line]
@init {line = new ArrayList<String>();}
  :  PIPE ( e=ELEMENT {line.add($e.text);} PIPE )*
  ;

PIPE
  :  '|'    
  ;

ELEMENT
  :  ('a'..'z')+
  ;

NL
  :  '\r'? '\n' |  '\r' 
  ;

WS
  :  (' '|'\t') {$channel=HIDDEN;} 
  ;
```

Now generate a lexer/parser by invoking:

```
java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool Route.g
```

create a class `RouteTest.java`:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import java.util.List;

public class RouteTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = 
        "a comment\n"+
        "| xxxxx | y |     zzz   |\n"+
        "another comment\n"+
        "| a | abc | b | def |";
    ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream(data);
    RouteLexer lexer = new RouteLexer(in);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    RouteParser parser = new RouteParser(tokens);
    parser.parse();
    for(List<String> line : parser.values) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
}
```

Compile all source files:

```
javac -cp antlr-3.2.jar *.java
```

and run the class `RouteTest`:

```
// Windows
java -cp .;antlr-3.2.jar RouteTest

// *nix/MacOS
java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar RouteTest
```

If all goes well, you see this printed to your console:

```
[xxxxx, y, zzz]
[a, abc, b, def]
```

Edit: note that I simplified it a bit by only allowing lower case letters, you can always expand the set of course.

Answer (score 0):

It's a nice idea to use ANTLR for a job like this, although I do think it's overkill. For example, it would be very easy to (in pseudo-code):

```
for each line in file:
if line begins with '|':
    fields = /|\s*([a-z]+)\s*/g
```

Edit: Well, you can't express the distinction between comments and lines *lexically*, because there is nothing lexical that distinguishes them. A hint to get you in one workable direction.

```
line: comment | fields;
comment: NONBAR+ (BAR|NONBAR+) '\n';
fields = (BAR NONBAR)+;
```

Comment: Well I agree, but I was trying to pick an easy thing to do with antlr to start out with.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, I swear I tried it.  Changing comment to lower case switched it to the parser vs the lexer, I still don't get it.

```
grammar Route;

@header {
    package org.benheath.codegeneration;
}

@lexer::header {
    package org.benheath.codegeneration;
}

file: (line|comment)+;
line: route+ '\n';
route: ('|' elt) {System.out.println("element: [" + $elt.text + "]");} ;
elt: (ELEMENT)*;

comment : ~'|' .* '\n';

ELEMENT: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'*'|'_'|'@'|'#') ;
WS: (' '|'\t') {$channel=HIDDEN;} ; // ignore whitespace
```

Comment: See my answer. It's a distinction between *lexing* (which turns text into tokens) and *parsing* (which understands tokens).